# Is it possible $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ not bounded and $\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$ bounded?

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x)\geq0$ and $g(x)\geq 0$ be two real functions

Is it possible that
$$
\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
is not bounded and$$
\dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}
$$ 
is bounded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then $\frac{f}{g} = x$ but $\frac{f}{\sqrt{g}} = 1$.

Comment: thanks @Patrick Stevens for your answer

Comment: Better to say that $0$ must be excluded from the domain of these functions for the equality to hold true.

Comment: yes, thanks, but for my problem it holds

Comment: @N74 Just give them any value at $0$, if necessary. Any completion at all to $\mathbb{R}$.